# Failed to create directory: joomla

Tags: joomla

when i am installing any module or component in my joomla1.5 i am getting the following problem, here i am showing an example, i am in big trouble please save me...

JFTP::mkdir: Bad response
JFTP::chmod: Bad response
Component Install: Failed to create directory.: "/home/butterfl/public_html/components/com_ckforms"

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that you have permission on the /tmp folder as well as this is where the file gets uploaded to before it's extracted. In addition, most components will extract to

/administrator/language

/administrator/components

/language

/components

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps checking directory permissions, seems to me that the web server isn't able to create since it doesn't have write permissions

check your webserver configured user, httpd.conf, or your web server config file, and give permissions to it on those directories so it can write in it.

also, you really should try at serverfault.com, ask there, this is mostly a programming/development consulting site.

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your permissions are set correctly, 777, 755 on your directories.  Also the chown should be correct as well.

Comment: hey i have change all the permission but still facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while trying to install a template on my 2.5.6 Joomla!.

To fix it I changed the configuration.php file as follow:
where was

```
public $error_reporting = 'default';
```

set to

```
public $error_reporting = '-1';
```